# App.PrevInstance not refreshing itself

Tags: vb6

I am trying to check to see whether another instance of the application is already running.  If it does, I want to keep on checking for another 15 seconds or so before going on...

```
if App.PrevInstance then 

  dim dtStart as date
  dtStart = now 

  do while datediff("s", dtStart, Now) < 15
    Sleep 1000  ' sleep for a second
    if not App.PrevInstance then exit do
  loop

end if
```

The problem is App.PrevInstance does not seem to refresh itself.  it keeps the initial value no matter what.

Is there another way to approach this?  Perhaps with API calls.  Note that the application may or may not have a window, thus I can't check for an existence of a window with a certain caption.

Comment: What part of "previous" was unclear? (-:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following class:

```
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ' Module    : CApplicationSingleton ' DateTime  : 24/03/2006 15:16 ' Author  : Fernando ' Purpose   : Enforces a single instance of an application. Uses a Mutex '             see http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?s=&threadid=293730 '             http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/W-P/system/processesmodules/article.php/c5745/ ' Copyright © 2001-2007 AGBO Business Architecture S.L. '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Explicit

Private Declare Function CreateMutex Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateMutexA" (lpMutexAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, ByVal bInitialOwner As Long, ByVal lpName As String) As Long Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

Private Type SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    nLength As Long
    lpSecurityDescriptor As Long
    bInheritHandle As Long 
End Type

Private Const ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS = 183&

Private m_hMutex As Long Private m_lLastDllError As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize() '

On Error GoTo errorBlock

'

Dim s As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES 
m_hMutex = CreateMutex(s, 0, rcString(8700)) m_lLastDllError = Err.LastDllError


'


exitBlock:
    Exit Sub
     errorBlock:

    Call GError.handleError(Err.Number, Err.Description, Erl, "CApplicationSingleton", "Class_Initialize", GApp.copyDebugFiles())
    Resume exitBlock


' End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate() On Error GoTo errorBlock


If m_hMutex > 0 Then
    Call CloseHandle(m_hMutex) End If


exitBlock:
    Exit Sub
     errorBlock:

    Call GError.handleError(Err.Number, Err.Description, Erl, "CApplicationSingleton.cls", "Class_Terminate")
    Resume exitBlock




End Sub


Public Function IsAnotherInstanceRunning() As Boolean '

On Error GoTo errorBlock

'

IsAnotherInstanceRunning = (m_lLastDllError = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)

'


exitBlock:
    Exit Function
     errorBlock:

    Call GError.handleError(Err.Number, Err.Description, Erl, "CApplicationSingleton", "IsAnotherInstanceRunning", GApp.copyDebugFiles())
    Resume exitBlock


' End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to give this a look: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=293730

Comment: +1, we use mutexes instead of App.Previnstance, they work fine. I haven't actually pored over the mutex API code in that link to make sure it's correct but it looks along the right lines.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Mutex class to work out the same issue with starting the same app multiple times.  It appeared to be working then stopped working returning a false positive.  What I found is that the vb6 IDE was also holding a mutex while the IDE was still open.

You've gotta use the code and compile it.  The EXE will work fine after you close the IDE.. Who knew? Drove me crazy(ier) for a few minutes..

I'll post a sample if anyone wants it.